# Right way to shift bits in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, hex

I have a 64-bits integer `id`, and I want to display the left most 32-bits. This could be done using [Shift operators in PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776355/shift-operators-in-pl-sql).

Indeed, these two lines gives the same result:

```
-- 1- not using a hex mask
select to_char(id / power(2, 32), 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXX') from dual;

-- 2- using a hex mask
select to_char( bitand(id, to_number('ffffffff00000000', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') / power(2, 32), 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXX') from dual;
```

However, I dont understand why the first line works, since `id` is not converted to hex or binary.

It seems the bitmask is not necessary, but I don't understand why.

Without it, doesn't it means that the decimal number will be divided by `2^32` ? Shouldn't this give a floating number in certain cases?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shift operators in PL/SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776355/shift-operators-in-pl-sql)

Comment: @kordirko I edited my question. Actually I don't really understand why the hex mask is unecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't really understand why the hex mask is unecessary.

Hmm, I really don't know how to explain this, I will try using an example.

The first command just takes a number and divides it by `power(2, 32)`.
This is equivalent to shifting a number by 32 bits to the right.
If you want to shift a number by 1 bit to right, just divide it by 2

To shift a number by 2 bits to the right, divide it by 2 * 2 (`power(2,2)`).
To shift a number by 3 bits to the right, divide it by 2 * 2 * 2 (`power(2,3)`).
......
To shift a number by 32 bits to the right, divide it by 2 * .... * 2 (`power(2,32)`).

Some simple examples - let say we have a number 12345 (decimal).
12345 (decimal) = 10011010010 (binary)
If we shift this number to the right by 1,2,3,4 bits, we should get:

```
+-----+------------------+------------------+
| bit | result binary    | result decimal   |
+-----+------------------+------------------+
| 0   | 11000000111001   | 12345            |
| 1   |  1100000011100   |  6172            |
| 2   |   110000001110   |  3086            |
| 3   |    11000000111   |  1543            |
| 4   |     1100000011   |   771            |
+-----+------------------+------------------+
```

If we run this query:

```
select 12345 / power(2, 0) x0,
       12345 / power(2, 1) x1,
       12345 / power(2, 2) x2,
       12345 / power(2, 3) x3,
       12345 / power(2, 4) x4
FROM dual;
```

we get these results (as decimal numbers):

```
        X0         X1         X2         X3         X4
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
     12345     6172.5    3086.25   1543.125   771.5625
```

If you take an integer part (before the dot) of these results and convert them to the binary notation, you will get shifted numbers from the above table.

**----------- EDIT ------------------**

> why select to_char(13 / 2, 'XXXXXXXX') from dual give 7 and not 6.5?

Because `to_char` function rounds the result due to a format XXXXX.
Refer to the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34510

> **XXXX**
>
> Returns the hexadecimal value of the specified number of digits. **If
>   the specified number is not an integer, then Oracle Database rounds it
>   to an integer.**

The below command gives 6.5

```
select 13 / 2 from dual;
```

The below command gives 7, 7, 6 because `to_char` function rounds numbers to integers due to XXXXX format used:

```
select to_char( 13 / 2, 'XXXXX' ),
       to_char( 6.5, 'XXXXX' ),
       to_char( 6.4, 'XXXXX' )
from dual;

TO_CHAR(13/2,'XXXXX') TO_CHAR(6.5,'XXXXX') TO_CHAR(6.4,'XXXXX')
--------------------- -------------------- --------------------
     7                     7                    6
```

Comment: thanks very much for this clear explanation. One thing still puzzles me, say I want to right shift the number '13', then why `select to_char(13 / 2, 'XXXXXXXX') from dual` give 7 and not 6.5?

Comment: I've updated the answer with explanation why Oracle returns 7 not 6.5

Comment: To sum up the issue with rounding: Use `floor` to get the integer value after division / shifting. Your example from the comment above thus would look like `select to_char(floor(13 / 2), 'XXXXXXXX') from dual`.